# pattern drawing programming logic

Tags: algorithm

I dont remember where the question is from.. but i came through the following :

if user intputs 3

the output should be :

```
1*2*3*10*11*12
--4*5*8*9--
----6*7----
```

if 5

then,

```
1*2*3*4*5*26*27*28*29*30
--6*7*8*9*22*23*24*25--
----10*11*12*19*20*21----
------13*14*17*18------
--------15*16--------
```

as you can see we are printing numbers from top to down then again going from down to top..
we can not use any formatting type functions  as we have `setw()` in c++.

can you give any algo / logic for the same..
thanks..

Comment: Can you post the code you've written so far, and point out where you're having a problem?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any logic involved going by the OP you have given, only that if there is 5 there needs to be 5 rows and if there's 3 then 3 rows?

Comment: m currently looking for the logic/ basic algo... which i am not able to devise so far..

Comment: Doesn't look too hard.

Comment: Why is it tagged `design-patterns` ?

Comment: Designing this puzzle console output doesn't meant design pattern .

Comment: it was looking close to pattern drawing.. i accept my mistake..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A C++ implementation :

*Without any formatting*

```
void print(int n) {
    for(int i=n, cl=1, cr=n*n+1; i>0; cl+=i, --i, cr-=i) {
        for(int j=0; j<i; ++j) cout << cl+j;
        for(int j=0; j<i; ++j) cout << cr+j;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

*With dashes and stars*

```
void print(int n) {
    for(int i=n, cl=1, cr=n*n+1; i>0; cl+=i, --i, cr-=i) {
        for(int j=0; j<n-i; ++j) cout << "--";
        for(int j=0; j<i; ++j) cout << cl+j << "*";
        for(int j=0; j<i; ++j) cout << cr+j << (j-i+1?"*":"");
        for(int j=0; j<n-i; ++j) cout << "--";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: i think `int i=n-i` is UB. if you coud remove `i` out of the equation it will be a perfect answer.

Answer (score 2):

You just printing M = n*(n+1) numbers in some pattern like..

let n=5 m=30 so,

list = 1,2,3,4,5,.....26,..30

Line (1) have (first n numbers followed last n numbers of list )

Line (1) =(1,2..5)(26..30)

Update list=6,7,..25

Line (2) have  (first n-1 numbers followed by n-1 numbers of list )

similarly Line(k) have (first (n+1-k) numbers in the list followed by last (n+1-k) numbers

of the list )

All you need to do is continuously update list on forming line and print them in your required pattern .

Comment: .how will u devise the starting number for new line.. give a general expression to find starting number only depending upon 'n'

Comment: Storing the position in row is one way .
removing the used numbers in the list is another way .
Stoving values as first and last , without using the list is another way . And there are many ways to that .

Answer (score 1):

```
Max value = sum for n=1 to R ( n + 2 )
Where R is the user supplied value

e.g. R=5 Max Value = 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 10 = 30

so lowest row = Max Value / 2 : (15), Max Value / 2 + 1: (16), 
entity count = 2

next row
LHS = 15-2, 15-1
RHS = 16+1, 16+2
entity count = 4 (it always goes up 2 entities at a time)

and repeat until you get a 1 at LHS first value
```

Enough of a clue?

Comment: Ah, MissingNumber's answer is nicer :-)

Answer (score 1):

ok divide the problem into lines. Assume that given number is `n`.

we can see that the first line is of size `2n`(variable for this V1)  and first `n` numbers are `1` through `n`(have a variable for this V2) next n numbers are `n*n+1` through `n*n+n`(have a variable for this V3)

second line is of size `2n-2` so first `n-1` are continuation of  previous V1 and second `n-1` are  `n*(n-1)` through `n*(n-1)+n`.

do this for rest of the lines..

last line should end with `(n-1) == 1`.

demo: for n = 5
first major loop

```
1.2.3.4.5.26.27.28.29.30
```

second major loop

```
--6.7.8.9.22.23.24.25--
```

third major loop

```
----10.11.12.19.20.21.
```

4rt

```
------13.14.17.18------
```

5th

```
--------15*16--------
```

now for the example in **C**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num = 7,
        //linesize = 2*num,  
        //space = 0,
        fst = 1,
        snd = 0;

  if(num%2)                              //for odd n
    snd = (((num*num)+num)/2)+1;
  else                                     //for even n
    snd = (((num*num)+num)/2);  

const int diff = (num*num)-snd+1; //needed to offset snd from its value and print the temporary

//printf("%d\n",snd);    //debug
for(int i = 0 ; i < num ; i++)
{
    //linesize = 2*(num-i);                   // no of elements to print per line, debug
    //space = i;                                // no of space to print per line, debug
    for(int k = 0 ;k <i;k++)printf("   ");   //space before the values

    for(int j = 0;j<(num-i);j++)
    {
        printf("%d  ",fst++); //print fst n numbers
    }

    //printf(" ");

    for(int j = 0;j<(num-i);j++)
    {
            printf("%d  ",snd+j+diff); // print second n numbers
    }
    snd -= (num-(i+1)); //decrement snd
    for(int k = 0 ;k <i;k++)printf("   ");
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: give general expression for starting number of second part of any line (say line no l)... depending upon only n and l...

Comment: snd should be half(or half+1 for odd) of the total values that are there.